# Sync iOS app using Wi-Fi network in Windows 7

Tags: ios, itunes, applications, data-synchronization, windows

I am using Windows 7 and have the latest version of iTunes installed.

The USB port is disabled for security purposes but I want to sync my iOS device to my PC, so I am thinking that I can use Wi-Fi. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to connect the device over USB the first time before you can use iTunes Wi-Fi Sync. For installing an IPA on your iOS device, iTunes manifests can be used to install IPAs directly on the iOS device. Alternatively, the developer can distribute the app to you using TestFlight.

Comment: But can not user USB as disabed by firewall. So there is no any other solution to sync app from PC?

Comment: @Helping No, although you can sync with iCloud, depending on exactly what you want to sync.

Comment: Actually I want to sync. ios app. IPA file which developer share with me in shared drive. So I get those IPA from shared drive to my PC and then sync in device for testing. Basically I am QA.

Comment: @Helping iTunes manifests can be used to install IPAs directly on the iOS device. Alternatively, the developer can distribute the app to you using TestFlight.

Comment: Ok thank you so much , Let me check for those 2 things.